# Pagination not working on Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am using CI3 and the pagination is not working on the second page. Is that i am missing something? Here is my code from the controller:

```
public function tags($task = "list")
{
    $header['title'] = 'Tag List';
    $this->load->view("template/header", $header);
    $this->load->view("template/dashboardNavView");

    $builder ['task'] = $task;

    if($task == "list" || $task == "")
    {

        $pager['base_url'] = "/dashboard/tags/";
        $pager['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('tags');
        $pager['per_page'] = 4;
        $pager["uri_segment"] = 3;
        $this->pagination->initialize($pager);

        $page = $this->uri->segment(3);

        $builder['tags'] = $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC')->limit($pager['per_page'], $page)->get('tags')->result();
        $builder['pager'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    }

    $this->load->view("tags/TagsBuilderView", $builder);
    $this->load->view("template/footer");
}
```

Everything seems ok, but when i click on the second link then empty view returned.

Comment: change this line $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

Comment: Changing this line doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Just want to point out that you shouldn't have db calls in your controller. Also, the uri->segment(3) will return the same value as $task. Not sure that it's what you want.

Comment: what is the link of your first and second page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use ship everything into a new method "list_tags()" within the controller.